# Information on WKT definition file

Tags: georeferencing, imagery, well-known-text, ecw

In a well known text definition file of a geolocated image (or whatever else it does) we find this:

> PROJCS["UTM_Zone_19_Northern_Hemisphere",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS84",SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.257223560493]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",**0.017453292519943295**]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-69],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]

My question is, what is the number I marked bold `(0.017453292519943295)` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0.017453292519943295 is the conversion factor from radians to decimal degrees, exactly `PI()/180`.

Geodetic functions usually expect angles in radians, but our surveying ancestors decided to use degrees, minutes and seconds.